# "Unrecognized character \xEF" Error with BOM-Free File

Tags: perl, csv, byte-order-mark

I am currently extracting text from CSV files using Perl and the module, [`Text::CSV`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text%3a%3aCSV).

Each of the CSV files have quotation marks separating each field. The texts are being saved to independent text files with tab separation into columns. I can call and print each column from the text files no problem, but when I try to use the values in a loop, I get the error `Unrecognized character \xEF`.

An example of my code is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV;

#### Match ligand data with GPCR interaction data ####
my $csv = Text::CSV->new();
my $file = $ARGV[0];
open (FILE, "<$file");
open (OUT, ">new_$file");
while (my $line2 = <FILE>)
{
    binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8");
    if ($line2 =~ /^(.*?)\t(.*?)\t(.*?)\t(.*?)\t(.*?)\t(.*?)\t(.*?)$/)
    {
        #### Data from filtered1.txt ####
        my $up_fil = $1;
        my $ligid_fil = $2;
        my $units_fil = $3;
        my $low_fil = $4;
        my $median_fil = $5;
        my $upper_fil = $6;
        my $ref = $7;

        #### Convert negative log affinity values to normal ####
        my $activity = $units_fil;
        $activity =~ s/p//;
        my $value;

        if （$median_fil ne "")
        { 
            $value = $median_fil;
            $value = (10**-$median_fil)/(10**-9);
        }
        elsif ($low_fil ne "" and $upper_fil ne "") 
        {
            my $lower = $low_fil;
            $lower = (10**-$low_fil)/(10**-9);
            my $upper = $upper_fil;
            $upper = (10**-$upper_fil)/(10**-9);
            $value = "$upper - $lower";
        }
        else
        {
            $value = "n/a";
        }


        #### Match entries from filtered1.txt with ligands.csv ####
        open (LIG, "<ligands.csv");
        while (my $line3 = <LIG>)
        {
            $csv->parse($line3);
            my @ligand_fields = $csv->fields();
            if (!$ligand_fields[14]) { next; }
            if ($ligand_fields[0] eq $ligid_fil)
            {
                #print OUT "$ligand_fields[14]\t$ligand_fields[13]\t$up_fil\t$ligid_fil\t$activity\t$value\t$ref\n";
                print "$ligand_fields[14]\t$ligand_fields[13]\t$up_fil\t$ligid_fil\t$activity\t$value\t$ref\n";
                next;
            }
        }
            close LIG;
        }
    }
    close FILE;
    close OUT;
```

I've also tried using a regex along the lines of the following, but to no avail.

```
# remove BOM
${$self->{CODE}} =~ s/^(?:
    \xef\xbb\xbf     |
    \xfe\xff         |
    \xff\xfe         |
    \x00\x00\xfe\xff |
    \xff\xfe\x00\x00
)//x;
```

The original CSV files appear not to have any BOM, so I suspect that `Text::CSV` may be creating it when it is parsing and returning values. I hope this was a clear enough explanation of the problem, and if needed, I can provide more details. Thanks in advance for any advice given.

Comment: You read in encoded bytes, then you tell STDOUT they are Unicode Code Points to be converted to UTF-8. Decode your input file to get Unicode Code Points!

Comment: Thanks for the edit, Miller. On another note, I figured out what was wrong. It turns out that there was a weird space-like character in between if and（$median_fil ne ""), causing the error. I deleted the space, added a new one in, and voila, the error went away. Thanks for the help, anyways!

Answer (score 2):

The documentation of `Text::CSV` states you should almost certainly be using the binary mode.

```
 my $csv = Text::CSV->new ( { binary => 1 } )  # should set binary attribute.
                 or die "Cannot use CSV: ".Text::CSV->error_diag ();
```

From [https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV#SYNOPSIS](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text%3a%3aCSV#SYNOPSIS).

You may also want to take a look at [`Text::CSV::Encoded`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text%3a%3aCSV%3a%3aEncoded).

I also see you are setting a binmode of `:utf8` on STDOUT. There are a couple of problems with that:

1. You are setting it each time around the loop unnecessarily
2. The `:utf8` binmode does not have good error checking, you should use `:encoding(UTF-8)` instead

The byte 0xEF can appear in UTF-8 byte sequences, but only in very specific circumstances, it is too high (> 0x7F) to be a single character. However in Perl `\xEF` or `\x{ef}` does not refer to the byte 0xEF, but the Unicode code point U+00EF which is represented in UTF-8 as 0xC3 0xAF. You can see this in a Unicode/UTF-8 character table such as http://www.utf8-chartable.de/.

```
$ perl -E 'binmode STDOUT, ":encoding(UTF-8)"; say "\xEF";'
ï
```

So I think that is why your regular expression to remove the BOM didn't work.

I would recommend using [three argument open](http://modernperlbooks.com/mt/2010/04/three-arg-open-migrating-to-modern-perl.html) with either `'<:encoding(UTF-8)'` or `'>:encoding(UTF-8)'` to open all of your input and output files, and using Text::CSV in binary mode, for the best results.

Comment: A byte `\xEF` can appear in valid UTF-8, but only if followed by 2 continuation bytes in the range `\x80..\xBF`.  (There might be other constraints on the following bytes, but that's the most basic one.)

Comment: Ah I see my mistake. In my Perl one-liner (`perl -E 'binmode STDOUT, ":encoding(UTF-8)"; say "\xEF";'`) the "\xEF" is referring to the Unicode code point U+00EF (which is "ï") not the byte EF which as you say is not a valid UTF-8 character. I'll update my answer, thanks.